# How to add xml file during installation using wix

Tags: wix

I want to create the following xml during the installation created by wix 3.9.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MappedUsers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UsersList>
    <LyncUserID>
      <CustomUserName>John.Smith</UcaUserName>
    </LyncUcaUserID>
  </UsersList>
</MappedUsers>
```

Tried creating the file using following code but got the error message during installtion that file doesn't exists.

```
<?define UserNameFile="[AppDataFolder]ThirdParty\LyncUcaUserMapping.XML" ?>

<util:XmlFile Id="UserMapping" Value="[USER_NAME]" ElementPath="/UsersList/LyncUserID/add[\[]@key='UcaUserName'[\]]" Action="setValue" File="$(var.UserNameFile)" Name="value" Sequence="7" />
```

Since I could not create the file during the installation I created the file manually and placed in my appdata folder. But then above code didn't work either as it says "failed to find the following node".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Best method to do this is first you copy a sample xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MappedUsers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

</MappedUsers>
```

Then edit it using a custom action.

Here is a link which shows how to edit xml files using c#

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301233

Following link shows how to add custom actions to a wix project.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html